# WPF/XAML: Binding expression error I don't understand

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, expression

> Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.
>   Value='D' target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

"D" is actually an enum value within a data class I wrote. I've overridden the classes `ToString()` to return enum values as a string and it seems to work. So I don't get this right now. How is 'D' not a valid string for this property?

Comment: Set your binding to `Mode=OneWay`

Comment: Sure that 'D' is a `string` not a `char`?

Comment: No, I will check on that. Shouldn't a textbox be able to handle that, though?

Comment: sa_ddam213: I need the TwoWay binding. I suspect the error is a bit misleading and probably due to a missing IValueConverter, though.